# Mirroring files from one partition to another on the second disk without RAID1

Tags: linux, file, directory, mirroring

I am looking for a program that would allow me to mirror one partition to another disk (something like RAID1) for Linux. It doesn't have to be a windowed application, it can be a console application, I just want what is in one place to be mirrored to another.
It would be nice if it were possible to mirror a specific folder that I would care for instead of copying everything from the given partition.

I was looking on the internet, but it's hard to find something that would give such opportunities, hence the idea to ask such a question.
I do not want to make fake RAID on Linux or hardware RAID because I read that if the motherboard fails then it is best to have the same second one to recover data.

I will be grateful for every suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check my script "CopyDirFile" written in bash, which is located on [github](https://github.com/MrGracu/CopyDirFile/).
You can perform a replication (mirroring) task of any source folder to another destination folder (deleting a file in the source folder means deleting it in the destination folder).
The script also allows you to create copy tasks (deleted files in the source folder will not be deleted in the target folder).

The tasks are executed in background at a specified time, not all the time, frequency is set by the user when creating the task.
You can also set the task to start automatically when the user logs on.
All the necessary information can be found in the README file in repository.

If I understood you correctly, I think it meets your requirements.

Comment: This is not RAID 1. RAID 1 means you can lose either of the copy without losing your data, and without even the file becoming unavailable. Your copying script doesn't give you either.

Comment: In my script you can set copy mode in one direction from source to destination. Then you can set another task from the same source to destination on another disk. Then you have this copy in two different destinations.

Comment: Yes, but the copy will often lag behind. That doesn't happen with RAID.

Comment: It is true, the copy is not made all the time on the fly, it is made every certain amount of time (specified by user). So it depends on how sensitive the data is and how often it is updated, if sporadically the script could be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Linux has standard support for software RAID: [mdraid](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_setup).
It allows you to bundle two disk devices into a RAID 1 device (among other things); you then create a filesystem on top of that device.

[LVM offers another way to do software RAID](https://serverfault.com/questions/217666/what-is-better-lvm-on-raid-or-raid-on-lvm); it doesn't seem to be very popular, but it's certainly supported.

(If your system supports hardware RAID, on the motherboard or with a separate RAID controller, Linux can use that, too, but that doesn't seem to be what you're asking here.)